what to consider when changing a parachain's spec_name?
We'd like to change the spec_name of our parachain. The reason is that we used identical runtimes for Polkadot and Kusama so far and used spec_name=integritee-parachain. With the upcoming bridging, however, the relay locations should be configured differently and we'd like to spilt runtimes into integritee-kusama and integritee-polkadot. This measn we need runtime upgrades on both parachains and spec_name won't match for this upgrade.
I'm aware we need to disable spec version checks for the runtime upgrade if we do this, but are there other considerations?
I saw that asset hub still has spec_name statemine/statemint, I guess this would have been changed if the change were risk-free.
